# adDBTimeStamp - Access VBA to SQL Server Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, vba, stored-procedures, odbc, parameter-passing

I am looking to pass a date variable from Access to a SQL Server stored procedure. Please see my code:

VBA:

```
searchDate = 03/07/2014
cmd.Parameters.Append _
        cmd.CreateParameter("@searchDate", adDBTimeStamp, adParamInput, , searchDate)
```

`searchDate` is a date formatted as `MM/DD/YYYY`

SQL:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spAppendActivity]
    @searchDate as datetime,
AS
   SET NOCOUNT ON;

   delete * from tbl_activity_losses;

   select [Date] 
   into tbl_activity_losses 
   from tbl_master_rec 
   where [Date] = @searchDate
```

I get an ODBC error stating

> [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver] Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Any help on how to pass this date field to my stored procedure would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try printing out the value of `@searchDate` in your sproc.  I bet it will be very different from what you think you are sending.

Comment: It is in the format (yyyymmddhhmmss plus a fraction in billionths). I am not sure how to alter my code to pass a value like this. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Is there any reason you chose a `adDBTimeStamp`?

Comment: I tried using adbdDate and it returns the error "[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver] Optional Feature Not Implemented. " I have not found a different way to pass a date variable. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: I see that you've posted this question before.  Did `adVarChar` work?

Comment: I tried this also, but I get a conversion error in the Stored Procedure as well. VBA 'cmd.Parameters.Append _
    cmd.CreateParameter("searchDate", adVarchar, adParamInput,10 , searchDate)' SQL: 'searchDate nvarchar(10) declare SPSearchDate datetime set SPsearchDate = CONVERT(datetime,searchDate,104)' ERROR: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string." My guess is there is something with my data types and CONVERT in the Stored Procedure?

Comment: Why are you using 104?  That formats like 30.12.2006.  I think you need 101, if you need ANY conversion at all.  http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1145/date-and-time-conversions-using-sql-server/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54946/discussion-between-paqogomez-and-user2989011).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55006/discussion-between-user2989011-and-paqogomez).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is `adDBTimeStamp`.  It is converting your simple date string into a timestamp. (NOT a date)

When that timestamp is passed to your stored procedure, SQL server has no idea how to turn that long string into a date.

Changing the type from `adDBTimeStamp` to `adVarChar` will keep it as a string and SQL Server will know how to parse it properly.

Additionally, you can change your stored procedure type from `DateTime` to varchar as well.  SQL Server will know how to parse that into a date.

Comment: When I try to pass it as varchar, I get the following ERROR: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string."