# Pass null datetime value to SQL Server stored procedure in VBA Access

Tags: sql-server, vba, ms-access, ms-access-2016

I use Access with SQL Server, in customer table (customer birth date is optional column), if user left it null while creating record by stored procedure date recorded as (30/12/1899) as shown in the screenshot:

[image: after creating record birth date field]

I found this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24003576/addbtimestamp-access-vba-to-sql-server-stored-procedure), but I really didn't figure it out where exactly I need to change in code or database.

I already tried following code in `access.vba` to pass empty date

```
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("@p_custi_birth_date", adDBTimeStamp, adParamInput, , Format(CDate(Nz(!custi_birth_date, Empty)), "YYYY-MM-DD"))
```

This is the SQL statement in the stored procedure to record null if parameter empty

```sql
CAST(NULLIF(@p_custi_birth_date, '') AS DATE)
```

Comment: The linked question in your post suggests using an  `adVarChar` data type for your parameter - but your code is still using `adDBTimeStamp`. I'm not sure why you are saying you don't know where to change that in the code. It's exactly in the line you posted - changing `adDBTimeStamp` to `adVarChar`. How about trying that fix? Although I'm not sure if casting `''` to date will actually work in your stored procedure ...

Comment: i tried nvarchar in database but i cant handle the conversion of nvarchar between access and sql server , always error because of windows date format , or access recordset , or sql server casting , if i convert to nvarchar i need to handle it every time when i select , update , insert , and all equations in queries which depend on difference between two dates.

Comment: Your last comment is very difficult to understand. It seems like you are over-thinking this. If you are passing a date string, then you are going to convert it to a date in your stored procedure. Everything should be fine in that case.

Comment: This is all pretty confusing but one very clear recommendation would be to only use `date` data types. Don't use character data types. Character data types are unecessary and just confuse the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not so sure about the vba side - I'm going to assume you follow the advice in the link you posted, which is to make sure you pass the date as a string, and also that the string is a valid date string that *sql server understands* - which to my mind means using `yyyy-mm-dd` or `yyyymmdd`, **not** using `mm/dd/yyyy` or `dd/mm/yyyy`, though feel free to try these latter if you must.

But in the stored procedure I don't think you want to cast an empty string to a date (you will get a date like 1900-01-01 which is not what you want). So this might work better for your stored procedure (assuming a valid date string is passed in, or otherwise an empty string, or possibly null):

```
-- //@p_custi_birth_date is a date string such as '2000-12-31'
case
    when isnull(@p_custi_birth_date, '') = '' then null 
    else cast(@p_custi_birth_date as date)
end
```

Comment: i think problem in `ms.access` side because i tried to execute stored procedure manually in sql server and i passed null date and every thing done well, so the problem still in access i cant pass null date to sql server

Comment: Have you tried any of the suggestions yet? There is one in the link you posted (to pass an `advarchar` instead of `adDbTImeStamp` (in which case you could pass either null, or an empty string, or a date string formatted so that sql server can work with it). There is another suggestion in another answer posted by nbk.

Comment: I'm always try to avoid usage of date as `varchar` , because it's really hard to handle between `access`  `and `SQLServer` i tried but always show errors in access code

Answer (score 0):

In Access and SQL Server, you can test the variable with `ISDATE`.

For SQL Server, it can be:

```
IIF(NOT ISDATE(@p_custi_birth_date), NULL, CAST(@p_custi_birth_date AS DATE))
```

For Access

```
IIf(IsNull(!custi_birth_date),Null,CDate(!custi_birth_date))
```

Comment: runtime error 94 invalid use of null , i think date fields not use Null concept

Comment: No that means that in your table definition you didn't allow null, but as you wanted there null I assumed that you field can accept null, so you need to alter the column